# Relation/difference between area calculated by PyQGIS QgsDistanceArea().measurePolygon() and QGIS $area

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

What is relation/difference between area calculated by `QgsDistanceArea().measurePolygon()` of PyQGIS and `$area` from geometry `$area` in QGIS?

I am getting area as 0 for one polygon using `QgsDistanceArea().measurePolygon()` in PyQGIS also when I compare the area calculated by above two methods for other polygons they don't have common multiplier.

Comment: See [this answer to "Area calculation in QGIS done two different ways?"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/234919/52808)